# OpenNI counting users and sending data thru OSC

Tags: c++, openframeworks

not very familiar with c++, but i'm trying to send some data to a java/processing sketch. The problem is I don't know how the user count is for Open Frameworks ofxOpenNI. I want to count as much as 3 users thru my kinect camera. Calculate an average of each user and send the data to my processing sketch for further use.

The problem is, that I get an infinity number of the second user sometimes. Could someone tell me why?

Using the OpenNISample007.xcodeproj

I've adapted this into the script:

```
        if (isMasking) drawMasks();
        for (int i=1; i< recordUser.getNumberOfTrackedUsers()+1; i++){
        if (isCloud) drawPointCloud(&recordUser, i);    // 0 gives you all point clouds; use userID to see point clouds for specific users
        }
```

then I use the pointCloud information to send an average thru OSC

```
 float  positionsX ;
float positionsBegin;
int counter = 0;
for(int y = 0; y < h; y += step) {
    for(int x = 0; x < w; x += step) {
        ofPoint pos = user_generator->getWorldCoordinateAt(x, y, userID);
        if (pos.z == 0 && isCPBkgnd) continue;  // gets rid of background -> still a bit weird if userID > 0...
        ofColor color = user_generator->getWorldColorAt(x,y, userID);
    //  glColor4ub((unsigned char)color.r, (unsigned char)color.g, (unsigned char)color.b, (unsigned char)color.a);
        glVertex3f(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);

        positionsX+=pos.x;
        if (x == 1){

            positionsBegin = pos.x;
        }
        counter++;


    }
}


float average = positionsX/counter;

cout<<"Average:"<<average<<endl;
//cout<<"positionsBegin:"<<positionsBegin<<endl;



ofxOscMessage m;
m.setAddress( "/persons" );
m.addIntArg( userID );

m.addFloatArg(average);


sender.sendMessage( m );
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you're looping through each user's pixel and trying to get to the centre ?
If you've got the user's you can use the [getCoM()](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/classxn_1_1_user_generator_a451c8a197374b567e62622f5edcb1670.html) method to get the each user's centre of mass, so you wouldn't need to loop through user pixels:

```
float positionX = 0;
int numUsers = user_generator.getNumberOfTrackedUsers();
for(int i = 0 ; i < numUsers; i++){
  XnPoint3D userPos;
  user_generator.getXnUserGenerator().GetCoM(i, userPos);
  positionX += userPos.X;
}
positionX /= numUsers;
```

Note that this will give you the coordinates in 3D space. If you want position on screen you'd need to convert the coordinates using [ConvertRealWorldToProjective](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/classxn_1_1_depth_generator_a70cda9f296d0ac90088cfafc34e9edd2.html#a70cda9f296d0ac90088cfafc34e9edd2)

Not sure if it helps, but you could do this directly in Processing using [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni)